How do I Dump MySql Tables One At a Time Using Python
I am using MySQL 5.6.21 on a Windows server and need to migrate from one machine to another.  Been trying to use the MySQL Workbench Export Tables and I keep getting an error 22 on write at some point during the export process.
I am using Jupyter for simplicity.
I want to try to dump each table individually and see which one is causing the issue.
So first thing I did was to write a test using one table, as follows:
import subprocess
tablename="templedger"
gettablestring="mysqldump -u user1 -pB57$52 db_main %s > G:\Databasebackup\dbmain\%s.sql" % (tablename,tablename)
subprocess.Popen(gettablestring, shell=True)
print("Done")

The word "Done" immediately came back, but no dump
I then tried the following
!{gettablestring}

And got "Access Denied"
How do I code this us so that I can execute the dump command from within a Jupyter cell?
Thanks

Remember to use a raw string when it contains literal backslash characters.

Can you try this please? Tell me if it works. I used communicate method instead of relying on shell=True here:
import subprocess

tablename = "templedger"
username = "user1"
password = "B57$52"
database = "db_main"
backup_path = "G:/Databasebackup/dbmain/"

escaped_password = password.replace("$", "\\$")
command = ["mysqldump", "-u", username, f"-p{escaped_password}", database, tablename]

with open(f"{backup_path}{tablename}.sql", "w") as output_file:
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=output_file, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

    if process.returncode != 0:
        print(f"An error occurred: {stderr}")
    else:
        print("backup completed successfully.")


That worked... thank you!  Any idea why what I tried didn't work?

First, in the gettablestring you used backslashes for the path, you need to escape those or use forward slashes. Second, directly interpolating the password into the command string, especially with special characters like $ probably caused the shell to misinterpret the command.
